# Alternative to time() function

Tags: c++, time.h, ctime

MISRA and AUTOSAR do not allow us to use the `time()` function of `<ctime>` (and `<time.h>`).

> Rule 18-0-4: The time handling functions of library `<ctime>` shall not be used.

Is there an alternative to the `time()` function in C++?

There is the time library `<chrono>`. But there I didn't find a function that returns the current time like `time()`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: [`std::chrono::system_clock::now()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/now)

Comment: @DrewDormann Wow! Very fast answer! Thanks!
Do I need to convert it to type time_t to get the same effect as time()?

Comment: [`std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/to_time_t)

Comment: @DrewDormann I know the function to_time_t, but my idea is correct, right? Thanks anyway!

Comment: Since the C function `time()` returns a `time_t` type, if you need that same effect (getting a time that's likely **much** lower-resolution) `to_time_t()` will produce that value.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `<chrono>` header requires a little more involvement than the time function.

You can create a `time_point` using `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`. Subtracting two `time_point` instances creates a `std::duration` which reflects the difference in time between the two instances. You can then use a `duration_cast` to cast this duration to a scale of your choice (microsecond, millisecond etc.) and then use the `count` member function to get the actual time in unsigned type.

TL;DR You can measure elapsed time between two events by doing this:

```
const auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); // event 1
// something happens in between...
const auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); // event 2
const auto time_elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start).count();
```

**Notes:**

1. `time_elapsed` is not a floating-point variable,
2. `std::chrono::steady_clock` should be preferred to `std::chrono::system_clock` because the former is a monotonic clock i.e. it will not be adjusted by the OS.

Comment: [AUTOSAR says](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/adaptive/18-10/AUTOSAR_RS_CPP14Guidelines.pdf): "Note: Facilities from `<chrono>` shall be used instead."

Comment: @Nitin_Malapally  Thanks! Wouldn't the following two lines be equivalent: (1) time(nullptr); and (2) system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::now()); ?
I don't understand exactly why I should also use duration_cast?

Comment: Video tutorial on C++11/14/17 `<chrono>`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M  It will cost you an hour, but hopefully will be worth it.

Comment: @KplnMoon You could do that as well. But like i said, the system clock may not necessarily be monotonic i.e. it could be reset. This means that you may find irregularities between timestamps.